# Como hacer bucle generico en JS

Tags: javascript, loops

He programado en otros lenguajes pero ahora me estoy poniendo con JavaScript.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
function Mix2( ValoresJ ) {

    var ai = ValoresJ

    var l00 = ai[0]
    var l01 = ai[1]
    var l02 = ai[2]
    var l03 = ai[3]
    var l04 = ai[4]
    var l05 = ai[5]
    var l06 = ai[6]
    var l07 = ai[7]
    var l08 = ai[8]
    var l09 = ai[9]
    var l10 = ai[10]
    var l11 = ai[11]
    var l12 = ai[12]
    var l13 = ai[13]

    var i00 = 0
    var i01 = 0
    var i02 = 0
    var i03 = 0
    var i04 = 0
    var i05 = 0
    var i06 = 0
    var i07 = 0
    var i08 = 0
    var i09 = 0
    var i10 = 0
    var i11 = 0
    var i12 = 0
    var i13 = 0

    var tfinal = []
    var lfinal = []

      for (var i00=0;i00<l00.length;i00++){
        for (var i01=0;i01<l01.length;i01++){
          for (var i02=0;i02<l02.length;i02++){
            for (var i03=0;i03<l03.length;i03++){
              for (var i04=0;i04<l04.length;i04++){
                for (var i05=0;i05<l05.length;i05++){
                  for (var i06=0;i06<l06.length;i06++){    
                    for (var i07=0;i07<l07.length;i07++){
                      for (var i08=0;i08<l08.length;i08++){
                        for (var i09=0;i09<l09.length;i09++){
                          for (var i10=0;i10<l10.length;i10++){
                            for (var i11=0;i11<l11.length;i11++){
                              for (var i12=0;i12<l12.length;i12++){
                                for (var i13=0;i13<l13.length;i13++){    

                                  lfinal.push(l00[i00])
                                  lfinal.push(l01[i01])
                                  lfinal.push(l02[i02])
                                  lfinal.push(l03[i03])
                                  lfinal.push(l04[i04])
                                  lfinal.push(l05[i05])
                                  lfinal.push(l06[i06])
                                  lfinal.push(l07[i07])
                                  lfinal.push(l08[i08])
                                  lfinal.push(l09[i09])
                                  lfinal.push(l10[i10])
                                  lfinal.push(l11[i11])
                                  lfinal.push(l12[i12])
                                  lfinal.push(l13[i13])

                                  tfinal.push(lfinal)

                                  lfinal = []

                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

    ss.getRange("PRUEBA!B1:O36").setValues(tfinal)

}
```

Básicamente lo que tengo es 14 celdas donde hay una serie de caracteres y lo que quiero es obtener todas las combinaciones posibles de todos los caracteres.

Lo que hago es pasar el contenido de las celdas a 14 arrays, cada array tendrá una posición por cada carácter.

Luego hago 14 bucles y obtengo el producto cartesiano.

Funciona bien pero me gustaría saber como hacerlo para que fuera genérico y así si a futuro en lugar de ser 14 son 20 o 30, no tenga que andar añadiendo cosas.

Comment: Perdon, el código no se ve bien

Comment: for (var i00=0;i00<l00.length;i00++){
    for (var i01=0;i01<l01.length;i01++){
      for (var i02=0;i02<l02.length;i02++){
        for (var i03=0;i03<l03.length;i03++){

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer una función recursiva. Sé que lo encontré por aquí y lo modifiqué, pero no encuentro la fuente.

Si tenemos un array como este:

```
var ai = [
    ['a','b','c'],
    ['d','e','f'],
    ['g','h','i','j'],
    ...
];
```

podemos generar las combinaciones con una función de este tipo:

```
function combinar(datos){
  if (datos.length == 1) {
    return datos[0];
  } else {
    var combinaciones = [];
    var restantes = combinar(datos.slice(1));
    for (var i = 0; i < restantes.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < datos[0].length; j++) {
        combinaciones.push(datos[0][j] + restantes[i]);
      }
    }
    return combinaciones;
  }

}

combinar(ai);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo vengo de programar en ABAP y estas cosas se suelen hacer como han propuesto en la primera respuesta, generas los nombres de las variables dinámicamente y vas accediendo a ellas con punteros o como sea.

Pero con JavaScript me esta pasando que siempre que hago un algoritmo para hacer algo me sale un engendro terrible luego ves que alguien hace lo mismo pero utilizando dos líneas de código.

Explorare ambas opciones y comentare aquí los resultados, muchas gracias por responder tan pronto.